# Enviar o caminho da imagem do js para o html - DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

Olá, preciso realizar um exercício simples com nós em js em que tenho que criar as tags de 6 cards e depois enviar o conteúdo desses cards pelo js, acontece que para mim ainda não é simples. Até consigo enviar todos os dados que o exercício propõe manipulando a DOM,e está tudo sendo renderizado na tela, menos as imagens, acredito que o erro está em não passar corretamente o valor do atributo criado 'src',já que, trocando meu arquivo de imagens por um endereço qualquer da internet, a imagem é renderizada:

```
        let elemento_pai= document.body;
        let divContainer= document.getElementsByClassName('container')
        let divItem = document.querySelectorAll('div')[0];
        let imgUrl = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
        let h2Title = document.getElementsByTagName('h2')[0];
        let textCard = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
        let created = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
        
        
        
        divContainer = document.createElement('div');
            elemento_pai.appendChild(divContainer);
            divContainer.classList.add('container')
        
        
        for (let index = 0; index < 6; index++){
        
            let divItem = document.createElement('div')
            divContainer.appendChild(divItem)
            divItem.classList.add('item')
           
        
            let imgUrl = document.createElement('img');
            divItem.appendChild(imgUrl);
            imgUrl.classList.add('imgCard')
            imgUrl.setAttribute('src','https://ciclovivo.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/12233034_943758819028895_1015830412_n.jpg');
            imgUrl.innerHTML  = listaDeFelinos[index].imgUrl;
            
           
            let h2Title = document.createElement('h2');
            divItem.appendChild(h2Title)
            //como renderizar o texto em cada card! O que vai ditar é o index!E a resposta estava na minha cara esse tempo todo!
            h2Title.innerHTML  = listaDeFelinos[index].title;
            
        
            let textCard = document.createElement('p');
            divItem.appendChild(textCard);
            textCard.innerHTML  = listaDeFelinos[index].description;
            
            let created = document.createElement('p');
            divItem.appendChild(created)
            created.innerHTML  = listaDeFelinos[index].createdAt;
        
            console.log(divContainer, imgUrl, h2Title, textCard, created);
        }
```

o conteúdo que precisa ser renderizado em cada card:

```
const listaDeFelinos = [

    //0
    {
        title: 'Tigre',
        imgUrl: './imagens/tiger.jpg',
        description: 'O tigre (Panthera tigris) é uma das espécies da subfamília pantherine (família Felidae) pertencente ao gênero Panthera. Encontra-se apenas no continente asiático; É um predador carnívoro e é a maior espécie de felídeo do mundo, juntamente com o leão, ambos podem atingir um tamanho comparável ao de fósseis de felinos maiores.',
        createdAt: '2021-06-01T23:12:11.837Z'
    },

    //1
    {
        title: 'Leão',
        imgUrl: './imagens/leon.jpg',
        description: 'O leão (Panthera leo) é um mamífero carnívoro da família Felidae e uma das cinco espécies do gênero Panthera. Os leões selvagens vivem em populações cada vez mais dispersas e fragmentadas na África subsaariana (exceto nas regiões de selva da costa atlântica e na bacia do Congo) e em uma pequena área do noroeste da Índia.',
        createdAt: '2021-05-05T23:12:11.837Z'
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

Em vez de definir o innerHTML tens que definir o atributo src.

```
imgUrl.setAttribute('src', listaDeFelinos[index].imgUrl);
```